# How to structure a SpecFlow project?

Tags: .net, specflow

So I really like Specflow, but as the project gets more complicated I fail to see how to do things in an organised way.

I know there are solutions like Scopes, ScenarioContext, and Feature context, but I have struggled to find any decent documentation, tutorials, or example projects to learn from.

Specifically I find that I can't reason a sensible way to reuse steps and avoid step collisions.

Can anyone point me at some decent resources to improve my usage?

Comment: Unfortunately this question is too broad.  This delves into application architecture, which is notoriously subjective. You will get as many answers as there are people.

Comment: I've got the same problem, I found e.g.
https://specflow.org/gherkin/outlines-background-or-hooks/
and there are some examples at
https://docs.specflow.org/en/latest/Examples.html
and 
https://docs.specflow.org/en/latest/specflowaction.html
but I think, them links will not be new to you.
If you find something better I would like if you post it here

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Selenium for automated tests in the browser. I have found this guide on creating a SpecFlow project that follows a specific structure. It follows the Page Object Model - basically creating a library of WebElements which you can reuse in your StepDefinitions. You can do witout too. It works really great for me, and I have succesfully added several other elements to structure the project with more advanced scenario's: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/ui-automation/Selenium-with-Page-Object-Pattern.html

- **1** Creating Folder 'Features' where .feature files are located
- **2** Copy the BrowserDriver.cs template responsible for starting the Lazy WebDriver
- **3** Setup the PageObject.cs class to create a library for WebElements or SetUp scenario's
- **4** If you have your .feature file, you can use the 'Define Steps...' to create a StepDefinitions.cs
- **5** Copy the SharedBrowserHooks.cs template
- **6** Setup the second Hooks.cs file to specify it for every individual application or .feature file (I have a Hook.cs file for every different application)

I have several more advanced elements integrated in the project like:

- appsettings.json Configuration
- SeleniumService.cs to handle generic Selenium actions
- FeatureContext and ScenarioContext keyloaders to use Context through Bindings instead of static globals
- Constants
- SpecSync integration in DevOps Test Plans to push scenario's in .feature files to the cloud environment
- DevOps pipeline including SpecSync publish-test-results on an agent in the cloud to synchronize test results to DevOps after executing